# React Native ScrollView disappears child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this code:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
  <ScrollView>
    <View style={{flex:0.25,elevation:2,marginVertical:5}}>
      <MoviesChild/>
    </View>
    <View style={{flex:0.75}}>
      <FlatList
        data={ListOfMovies}
        renderItem={this.renderData.bind(this)}
        keyExtractor={(x, i) => x.id}
        extraData={this.state}
      />
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

The problem is, my FlatList's data appears but my child component `MoviesChild` disappears. Maybe Flatlist overlaps the child component. Could someone figure out where I'm doing a mistake please?

Answer (score 0):

You should give style to ScrollView with flexGrow:1

Comment: Thank you for your Reply ., 

That does'nt work for me., i already tried like that

Comment: I Mean the Child Component Appears But The Scroll doesn't works.., for the entire view

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
              <View style={{ flex:0.25,elevation:2,marginVertical:5 }}>
                <MoviesChild/>
              </View>
                <FlatList
                  style={{flex:0.75}}
                  data={ListOfMovies}
                  renderItem={this.renderData.bind(this)}
                  keyExtractor={(x, i) => x.id}
                  extraData={this.state}
                 />
</View>
```

Comment: Thank you for your Reply., Child Component Appears But Scroll Doesn't works for me

Comment: check my updating answers

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you not to use `FlatList` inside a `ScrollView`, 'cause `FlatList` scroll itself. So, in order to achieve your objective, wrap your first `View` in a function and pass it to the `ListHeaderComponent` property of your `FlatList`, like this:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
  <View style={{flex:0.75}}>
    <FlatList
        data={ListOfMovies}
        renderItem={this.renderData.bind(this)}
        keyExtractor={(x, i) => x.id}
        extraData={this.state}
        ListHeaderContainer={this.renderHeader}
        />
  </View>
</View>
```

where

```
private renderHeader = () => {
  return(
    <View style={{flex:0.25,elevation:2,marginVertical:5}}>
        <MoviesChild/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

I hope this can fix your issue!
You can find what I'm talking about on the official [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#listheadercomponent)